# How do I get Adobe Reader to produce efficient XPS

Tags: pdf, xps

When I print certain PDF files from Adobe Reader via the **Microsoft XPS Document Writer**, the XPS written by the driver expresses the text from the PDF as many XPS `<Path>` elements, rather than as the more efficient XPS `<Glyphs>` elements.

I cannot find any posting on the Adobe Acrobat forum or anywhere else that gives any sort of clue why Adobe Reader behaves like this.

Two questions:

1. Why does Adobe Reader do this?
2. Is there any way of forcing Adobe Reader to produce XPS that favours the `<Glyphs>` representation over  `<Path>` ?

Comment: Are the texts in those certain pdfs probably also actually paths? Or are they using type 3 fonts?

Comment: Are you creating these PDFs programmatically?

Comment: Very many thanks for the follow-up questions. The produced XPS contains only <Paths> - no <Glyphs> at all. So I don't think this is a side-effect of the font type within the PDF, otherwise I'd expect to see a mix of <Glyphs> and <Paths>. We have to post-process the XPS so we'd like it to be created as fast as possible and be as small and efficient as it can be.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to control the XPS creation process from Acrobat, but it's not intuitive that you should have control of it since it's not available as a format to Save to, but rather available as a print to option.

I would think the print driver is mostly responsible for the formulation of the XPS content.  Have you verified an alternative PDF viewer using the *same* XPS driver produces the content you would expect?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I tried printing from Foxit PDF Reader and the produced XPS file was smaller and used <Glyphs> - rather than using <Path> throughout like the XPS printed from Adobe Reader.